# window.opener.location.href is malfunctioning in IE8 with WIN-7

Tags: internet-explorer

I have an applcation that launches a popup using the window.open(url) as given below.

**function goRelURL(){ winObj=window.open(url,"w1"); winObj.focus(); }**

From the popup I am closing the popup on click of a button. on click a methods is called and from there I set the URL for parent window and close the popup as:

**window.opener.location.href='<%=url%>'; window.close();**

This works fine with IE6, IE8 and Firefox3.0 with WIN-XP. But it fails in IE8 with Windows-7. with win-7 it set the url of the popup and popup remains open.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Yeah been seeing this myself, what is odd is that it works in debug mode but not when I turn off debugging and refresh the page. I get a script error window.opener.locaton is null or not an object

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, our Intranet site calls out to a 3rd Party ordering system on the internet and has some data passed back etc, well this call was key to the refresh of the calling page and the whole process. Only appears as a problem with Windows 7 and IE8 when changing between security zones, if the security zones were the same this didn't occur.

Essentially the issue seemed to be that IE8 no longer allows you to send data between sites within different security zones, it loses track of the window.opener, it doesn't seem to matter what security settings you actually have in the zone as long as the 2 sites are within it.

So my original "solution" suggestion was

On Windows 7 and IE 8 by changing the setting under 
Internet options -> security -> Enable Protected mode (requires restarting IE) will allow this to work once again, although as to why and what other side effects it has I am yet to discover.

This obviously effects every site you run, my assumption was that this set it back to work the way it always used to although I still don't completely understand why turning on Protected Mode == "disabling a system critical security feature", surely enabling protected mode should be more protected or its a badly named setting!

Anyway regardless you can get the same "fix" by adding the site that is on the internet to your trusted sites and essentially treat it as an intranet site. Or vice versa, the problem is the change in protected mode.

I also had some success with running the site within the same window - although I think I recoded and just set the windows location and removed the need for window.opener.

Comment: The side effects are that you are disabling a critical security feature. Furthermore, this shouldn't actually even help, unless your main window and popup window are running in different security zones (e.g. one Intranet, one Internet)

Comment: Side effects aside, assuming a public facing website, this solution doesn't scale...